# Map Enum field with MapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, mapstruct

I want to map 2 models, where each of them has almost the same enums. Let me show:

The first model has enum:

```
public enum EventSource {
  BETRADAR("SOURCE_BETRADAR"),
  BETGENIUS("SOURCE_BETGENIUS"),
  BETCONSTRUCT("SOURCE_BETCONSTRUCT"),
  MODEL("SOURCE_MODEL");
```

Second model has enum:

```
public enum SportEventSource implements ProtocolMessageEnum {
  SOURCE_UNKNOWN(0),
  SOURCE_BETRADAR(1),
  SOURCE_BETGENIUS(2),
  SOURCE_BETCONSTRUCT(3),
  UNRECOGNIZED(-1);
```

I have such custom mapping method:

```
@Named("eventSourceConverter")   
default EventSource eventSourceConverter(SportEventSource source) {
        switch (source) {
          case SOURCE_MODEL:
            return EventSource.MODEL;
          case SOURCE_BETCONSTRUCT:
            return EventSource.BETCONSTRUCT;
          case SOURCE_BETGENIUS:
            return EventSource.BETGENIUS;
          case SOURCE_BETRADAR:
            return EventSource.BETRADAR;
          default:
            return EventSource.MODEL;
        }   
}
```

And then I use:

```
  @Mapping(target = "mainSource", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "eventSourceConverter")
  AdapterCompetitor protoToModel(Competitor proto);
```

But get:

```
error: The following constants from the property "SportEventSource source" enum have no corresponding constant in the "*source*" enum and must be mapped via adding additional mappings: SOURCE_UNKNOWN, SOURCE_BETRADAR, SOURCE_BETGENIUS, SOURCE_BETCONSTRUCT, UNRECOGNIZED.
  AdapterCompetitor protoToModel(Competitor proto);
```

I've also created the enum mapper like:

```
  @ValueMappings({
      @ValueMapping(source = "SOURCE_BETRADAR", target = "BETRADAR"),
      @ValueMapping(source = "SOURCE_BETGENIUS", target = "BETGENIUS"),
      @ValueMapping(source = "SOURCE_BETCONSTRUCT", target = "BETCONSTRUCT"),
      @ValueMapping(source = "SOURCE_MODEL", target = "MODEL"),
      @ValueMapping(source = "SOURCE_UNKNOWN", target = "MODEL"),
      @ValueMapping(source = "UNRECOGNIZED", target = "MODEL")
  })
  EventSource eventSourceToSportEventSource(SportEventSource source);
```

But I don't need to have it separately, just want that enum field will be mapped within the internal mapping. Simply to say — when I do `AdapterCompetitor protoToModel(Competitor proto)` enum also should be mapped.

Thanks!

p.s. sorry for my eng, hope my questions make sense :)

Comment: Hi, maybe I misunderstood the question, but why you cannot use @ValueMappings method inside your main mapper and use it as your custom mapping? How i know mapstruct generate the same logic as your method. See more [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_mapping_enum_types)

Comment: Hi Alex! Thanks for the link, I've used it for generating the single enum mapping method (see eventSourceToSportEventSource), but not sure how I can map the exact field of the object using @ValueMappings inside the main mapper

Comment: MapStruct make mapping "by type" and if you just add method with @ValueMappings to main mapping class, then main mapping  method will use this method to map your enums by default. I think it should work out of box.

Comment: The error you are getting is weird. Can you please add your entire mapper and the objects to the question. With the information you've provided currently this should be working correctly (no error message)

Comment: Hey @Filip, nice to see the member of the core MapStruct team here :) MapStruct works well, it was my mistake, details in the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: We try to answer as many questions to our users on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ConverterMapper {
  @Named("UnitValueConverter")
  default Long unitValueConverter(UInt64Value value) {
    return value.getValue();
  }
```

as an interface which contains all named mappers like above, and then I do

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface EventMapper extends ConverterMapper
```

The issue was that I didn't add the @Mapper annotation to the `ConverterMapper` interface

Comment: Makes sense. Just FYI, it seems like the `ConverterMapper` is only for utils. If that's the case you don't need to annotate it with `@Mapper`. You can also add any utils via `Mapper#uses` and make your `unitValueConverter` a static method.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using [@ValueMapping](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/ValueMapping.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the most convenient way is just to make a default method in your mapper

```
default ProblemStatus problemStatusFromString(String status) {
    return ProblemStatus.get(status);
}

default String problemStatusToString(ProblemStatus problemStatus) {
    return problemStatus.getValue();
}
```